# Will formatting memory stick in a pc make it not recongnizable by the camera or other devices?

Tags: formatting, memorystick

I need to format my memory stick as it has supposedly developed bad sectors according to the technician. Formatting it with the camera didn't fix things. Before I format it using a PC I need to know if it would go unrecognizable when formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format it from your PC. Make sure to format as `fat32` (your OS may call it just `fat`, or some minor variation on that, it's ok), but it's likely to be the default for a memory stick.

However, if the memory stick has bad sectors, formatting won't help (though it might hide the problem for a while... until you can't read back your photos). It's a hardware problem and requires the hardware to be replaced. If a technician told you to just format it, he may have been trying to dissuade you from a warranty return.

Answer (score 0):

It is gonna be recognizable for sure. As long as you format it in FAT32. Maybe NTFS will work, but it is safer to format it in FAT32.